# Бинарное дерево, удаление элемента.

Tags: c, бинарное-дерево

Здравствуйте. Есть код на СИ, реализующий бинарное дерево. И вот в этом коде упорно косячит метод удаления узла из дерева. Причем я не могу понять, где конкретно, потому что это может случиться и после 500 удалений, и после 1000. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку. Код ниже.

```
    typedef struct binaryTreeItem
{
    //char *key;
    keyType key;
    int value;
    struct binaryTreeItem *left;
    struct binaryTreeItem *right;
    struct binaryTreeItem *parent;
} BinaryTreeItem;
#define BINARYTREE_ITEM_SIZE sizeof(BinaryTreeItem)

static BinaryTreeItem *BinaryTree;

void AddBinaryTreeItem(keyType key, int value)
{
    BinaryTreeItem *current, *newBinaryTreeItem;

    newBinaryTreeItem = (BinaryTreeItem*) mm_alloc(BINARYTREE_ITEM_SIZE);
    newBinaryTreeItem->key = key;
    newBinaryTreeItem->value = value;

    if(BinaryTree!=NULL)
    {
        current=BinaryTree;
        while(1)
        {
            if(key < current->key)
            {
                if(current->left!=NULL)
                    current=current->left;
                else
                {
                    newBinaryTreeItem->parent = current;
                    current->left = newBinaryTreeItem;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if(key > current->key)
            {
                if(current->right!=NULL)
                    current=current->right;
                else
                {
                    newBinaryTreeItem->parent = current;
                    current->right = newBinaryTreeItem;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    else
        BinaryTree = newBinaryTreeItem;
}

BinaryTreeItem *find_node(keyType key)
{
    BinaryTreeItem *current=BinaryTree;
    while(current!=NULL)
    {
        if(key<current->key)
            current=current->left;
        else if(key>current->key)
            current=current->right;
        else
            return current;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int* GetBinaryTreeValueByKey(keyType key)
{
    BinaryTreeItem *p;
    p = find_node(key);
    if(p==NULL)return NULL;
    return &p->value;
}

BinaryTreeItem *get_successor(BinaryTreeItem *node)
{
    BinaryTreeItem *current;
    if(node==NULL)
        return NULL;
    if(node->right!=NULL)
    {
        for(current=node->right;;current=current->left)
            if(current->left==NULL)
                return current;
    }
    else
    {
        for(current=node;current->parent!=NULL;current=current->parent)
            if(current==current->parent->left)
                return current->parent;
        return NULL;
    }
}

void Remove(BinaryTreeItem *node)
{
    BinaryTreeItem *succesor;
    if(node==NULL)
        return;
    if(node->left!=NULL&&node->right!=NULL)
    {
        succesor=get_successor(node);
        node->key=succesor->key;
        node->value=succesor->value;
        Remove(succesor);
    }
    else if(node->left!=NULL)
    {
        node->left->parent=node->parent;
        if(node==node->parent->left)
            node->parent->left=node->left;
        else
            node->parent->right=node->left;
        mm_free((char*)node);
    }
    else if(node->right!=NULL)
    {
        node->right->parent=node->parent;
        if(node==node->parent->right)
            node->parent->right=node->right;
        else
            node->parent->left=node->right;
        mm_free((char*)node);
    }
    else
    {
        if(node->parent->left==node)
            node->parent->left=NULL;
        else
            node->parent->right=NULL;
        mm_free((char*)node);
    }
}

void DeleteBinaryTreeItem(keyType key)
{
    BinaryTreeItem *node;
    node = find_node(key);
    Remove(node);
}
```

Comment: @hdimon, для начала я что-то не пойму, как у вас одинокий корень удалиться?

IMHO parent, left и right у него NULL, и тогда в Remove() 

    if(node->parent->left==node) 

сразу уронет программу. 

Или я что-то недосмотрел? (mm_alloc() не нашел).

Comment: Возможно, Вы правы, но понимаете, падает она, когда у нее около 10 тысяч узлов. У меня уже несколько реализаций разных, и все равно падает. Так что проблему одинокого узла я бы пофиксил, но дело не в ней.

Comment: @hdimon, а в отладчике в месте падения не смотрели?

Вообще, я как-то не понимаю идею с get_succesor() и его рекурсивным удалением.

IMHO здесь (случай, когда у удаляемого узла есть оба поддерева) можно проще. 

Ищете самый левый (это минимальный) лист в правом поддереве. Цепляете левое поддерево к его left. Цепляете правое поддерево удаляемого узла к родителю (Вот тут возникает вопрос с удалением корня. Им можно сделать этот самый, только что найденный лист).

Удаляете узел.

IMHO как-то так.

--

Правда остается вопрос, а зачем вообще нужно программировать **несбалансированное** дерево?

Comment: Даже не знаю, получается, что ответ на мой вопрос не имеет ничего общего с самим вопросом. Может, совсем уж удалить тогда?

Comment: @hdimon, оставьте. Я лучше преобразую Ваш комментарий о mm_alloc() в ответ. 

А с корнем разберитесь, и о балансировке задумайтесь. Хотя, если задача такая, что ключи случайны, то без нее проще.

Comment: @avp , спасибо Вам большое. С корнем я разобрался, просто взял другой алгоритм удаления узла, для которого даже parent не нужен. Я его сначала написал, потом, когда увидел, что не работает, начал пробовать другие. А они тоже не работали:). Вот и скопировал сюда тот, что поменьше.
Насчет балансировки - да, условия таковы, что данные перемешаны практически равномерно, поэтому особого смысла перестраивать дерево нет.
Да, и рекурсии в первой версии алгоритма, которую я сейчас и оставил, у меня нигде нет - медленно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот только плюнул на все, и коли все равно потерял около 7 часов на это, сделал дерево на 10 узлов, запустил функцию, взял бумажку, перерисовал дерево, и смотрел пошагово, что же с ним происходит. К счастью, я нашел, в чем "ошибка". Мой пример может быть хорошим уроком другим лошпендам, как я, что пренебрег некоторыми свойствами языка.

`mm_alloc()` - функция планировщика памяти, который выделяет блоки нужного размера. 
`mm_free` освобождает блок. Рано или поздно выделяется блок, который ранее уже был выделен. А при создании узла я не делаю `newBinaryTreeItem->right(left) = NULL`. Думаю, понимаете, что происходит дальше :).

Comment: Лучше в подобных случаях просто обнулять весь отдаваемый из аллокатора блок.